# When to use child process over worker threads?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, electron, node-worker-threads

I'm still trying to understand what is worker threads, and how it's different from child process so please bear with me.

So I'm currently building a desktop app with Node.JS + Electron. The app would work with several tasks at a time, which some of them are CPU and I/O intensive tasks.

The architecture currently has 1 main process, and numbers of child process which follows the number of host's CPU core count.

The main process handles Electron instance, renderer process, local database process, and handle the other child processes.
Meanwhile child processes would do the other tasks that is CPU and I/O intensive in nature.

So far, I have *4* questions here:

1. In my case, is it more beneficial to use worker threads instead?
2. If a tasks requires several package / library, does worker threads will require them first each time the task is run?
3. Currently, child process has no access to Electron API, thus only main process handles them. Does using worker threads allows me to handle Electron API?
4. In simple term, what's the difference between worker threads and threads pool? and should I use it instead of the other 2 (child process and worker threads)?

Comment: IO-intensive work should not need separate threads/processes in JS

Comment: I'd say the difference between worker processes and worker threads is how the OS handles them and the (un)ability to share/transfer memory.

Comment: "*Will worker threads require libraries each time the task is run?*" - yes, if you're spawning a new thread for each task. No if you're using a pool.

Comment: it's also CPU intensive tasks so I take the child process approach. I'm not sure I follow the term "share / transfer memory", can you please enlighten me on that part? should I use thread pool instead of my current approach?

Comment: Another interesting aspect is that, on most OS, a multi-threaded process can be completely terminated with a one-line OS call, even if very complex with threads in any state.  With multiple processes, you have to make sure that you don't leave any "lying around' when shutting down:)

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#worker-threads: "*Unlike child_process or cluster, worker_threads can share memory. They do so by transferring `ArrayBuffer` instances or sharing `SharedArrayBuffer` instances.*"

Comment: @MartinJames I certainly didn't know that. I thought Node.JS would handle it automatically when the main process was killed. Is it just generally bad to use child process over worker threads?

Comment: I made an edit to the question. please post your answer instead of posting a comment here. thank you very much.